# Decoding cross-references between different elements of JSON response

Tags: php, json

I'm decoding a JSON response and outputting it in a table. JSON response is separated in three elements (`Events`, `Organizers` and `Venues`) and `Events` nodes reference nodes from `Venues` and `Organizers` elements.

Here is an example of what `print_r` displays for the JSON response:

```
Array
(
    [Events] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [EventTitle] => Concert One                 
                    [Details] => Array
                        (
                            [VenueID] => 100
                            [EventDate] => 2016-01-01
                        )
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [EventTitle] => Concert Two
                    [Details] => Array
                        (
                            [VenueID] => 150
                            [EventDate] => 2016-01-02
                        )
                )

          )

    [Venues] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [HallID] => 100
                    [VenueName] => Venue A
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [HallID] => 150
                    [VenueName] => Venue B
                )

        )

)
```

Actual JSON example looks like this:

```
{
    "Events": [
        {
            "EventTitle": "Concert One",
            "Details": {
                "VenueID": 100,
                "EventDate": "2016-01-01"
            }
        },
        {
            "EventTitle": "Concert Two",
            "Details": {
                "VenueID": 150,
                "EventDate": "2016-01-02"
            }
        }
    ],
    "Venues": [
        {
            "HallID": 100,
            "VenueName": "Venue A"
        },
        {
            "HallID": 150,
            "VenueName": "Venue B"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is foreach loop that I use to create the table:

```
<?php

foreach($results['Events'] as $values)

{
        echo '<tr><td>' . $values['EventTitle'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $values['Details']['VenueID'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $values['Details']['EventDate'] . '</td></tr>';
}

?>
```

It works well and creates a simple table:

```
Event title | Event venue | Event date
Concert One | 100 | 2016-01-01
Concert Two | 150 | 2016-01-02
```

What I'm struggling with is how to replace `Venue ID` (100, 150) with `VenueName` (Venue A, Venue B), so that the result is:

```
Event title | Event venue | Event date
Concert One | Venue  A | 2016-01-01
Concert Two | Venue  B | 2016-01-02
```

Is it possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach($results['Events'] as $values)

{
        echo '<tr><td>' . $values['EventTitle'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $results['Venues'][array_search($values['Details']['VenueID'], array_column($results['Venues'], 'HallID'))]['VenueName'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $values['Details']['EventDate'] . '</td></tr>';
}

?>
```

Everything in one line!

Comment: I get these errors for the first one: Warning: Illegal string offset 'Venues'
Warning: array_column() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given
Warning: array_search() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given

Comment: Are you sure `$result` contains what you said in your question? The error says `$result['Organizers']` is null

Comment: Other parts of foreach loop work properly, so it should contain it all. I have simplified the question (removed the part about the organizers and left only Venues, structure is the same anyway). I did make a typo - ID in the Events elements has "VenueID" identifier, but Venues element has "HallID" identifier.

Comment: Same errors. It looks good, so I'll have to look into it a bit more, I don't get what's wrong.

Comment: I have tried separating it all and running just the first part: <?php foreach($results['Events'] as $values) { echo $results['Venues']; } It displays "Notice: Array to string conversion"

Comment: I had a typo in my code. Wrote `$result` instead of `$results`. Try it again

Comment: I have corrected that, no worries, but it displays that error. Did you try to run that code with this json example? You don't see any errors?

Comment: Actually I can not try it, because the print_r format is not parsable by PHP.

Comment: I have added pure JSON to the example.

Comment: The code works for me just fine. Only added `$results = json_decode('json', true);` and output is `<tr><td>Concert One</td><td>Venue A</td><td>2016-01-01</td></tr><tr><td>Concert Two</td><td>Venue B</td><td>2016-01-02</td></tr>`

Comment: I must be doing something wrong there, I'll try again later and let you know if I make it work.

Comment: I'll be happy to help you, anyway!

Comment: I have finally made it work few days ago. It actually has a nice advantage compared to the other solution - if some of the nodes don't have certain elements, it won't display any errors. Therefore, I have switched the accepted answer to your solution.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is parse your `Organizers` and `Venue` into their own arrays, with the ID as the key. So you would have an array like this (where `$arr` represents the variable holding the full array)

```
$venue = [];
foreach($arr['Venue'] as $vals) {
    $venue[$vals['HallID']] = $vals['VenueName'];
}
```

You could build that with a `foreach` loop. Then, you would iterate over your `Events`, using the keys to get the correct relationship data (do the same thing to build `$organizers` as `$venue`)

```
foreach($results['Events'] as $values) {
     echo '<tr><td>' . $values['EventTitle'] . '</td>';
     echo '<td>' . $venue[$values['Details']['VenueID']] . '</td>';
     echo '<td>' . $organizer[$values['Details']['OrganizerID']] . '</td>';
     echo '<td>' . $values['Details']['EventDate'] . '</td></tr>';
}
```

Comment: That sounds interesting, but I'm confused with the first part. Aren't Organizers and Venues already arrays?

Comment: They are, but they're structured in such a way that it's not useful to you directly. Assuming that's in an a single variable you'd have `$ar['Values'][0]['VenueID']` and then you'd have to iterate each element (very time consuming). By building a different array that's `$venue[100] = 'Venue A';` you now have a data structure that works with your data and is 100% scaleable.

Comment: Sorry for taking me so long to try this, I'm looking for a way to build that first array (for Venues element).

Comment: Finally it works! :) I have just corrected Venue to Venues and $arr to $results. in the first foreach and it all works properly. Thank you!!